# Google Cloud MySql Instance An unknown error occurred when importing

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I created a mysql instance and everything is running on it. I used the process outlined in the cloud sql import to create a mysqldump file from my local production mysql instance running on windows.

mysqldump --databases xxxxx -uroot -p --hex-blob --default-character-set=utf8 > d:\database_file_feb2_2014.sql

Uploaded the file to the cloud storage and every time I try to import I get a Unknown error.
Things I have checked.

1) Made sure the USE database; command was in the file after the 
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS databasename;
command.
2) Made sure i was using the --hex-blob command.

created a export of smaller test db which was only 4.5MB instead of the 6GB file i was trying to import. Ran the first few lines from the sql prompt which ran fine.
Still unable to isolate at which line the import is breaking or Why

When I try to view the log from the old console, I get "An error has occurred. Please retry later."

I have dumped the whole instance and recreated the instance and still get the same error.

Origin OS: Windows Server 2003 R2
Running Mysql 5.1

Any advise on how I can troubleshoot this and move forward.

Thank you

Comment: update: I used the mysql client to import the data from a remote machine to my google instance and the import succeeded without issues. Did not think this would be a good idea for a 6GB database. My data does have geometry information if that makes a difference. Thanks

Comment: Geometry information is most likely the culprit. Cloud SQL currently restricts the import file to be in UTF8 encoding only.

Comment: Hi Tony,Thanks for the response. There are a couple of threads on the old google groups where the topic has been taken offline for help. Anyone can shed some light on how this can be done. I tried it from the command prompt from a remote server but since the import was big it got disconnected before completing.

Comment: How big is the geometric data set? If it's not big, would it be possible to import it separately through mysql client and import other data through the normal import path?

Comment: If that's not an option, another thing to try is to upload the data to a compute engine instance first and then do the import from there via mysql client.

Comment: The dataset is about 6GB. I am trying to see how to break up the dataset and import remotely through mysql client. Did not understand uploading data to a compute engine first and then import. Would that not create the same problem as I would have with the remote mysql client as the timeout is probably from the cloud sql instance ? Thanks

Comment: I've got the same issue as well, but if done remotely using MySQL workbench it seems to work fine. Must be something wrong with Google's import.